# Sending a command to terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Mpsyt is a terminal based library for Python. It provides to searching and playing music on youtube. This code which provides searching on youtube:

```
os.system("mpsyt search creep")
```

But then, i need to send a command to terminal which is "1". Because this "1" plays first music on searching list. How will i send "1" command to shell which is exist?

Comment: Look into the `subprocess` module. I forget which member function allows you to send a list of args which are executed in order (maybe `Popen()`?)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code..

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(['mpsyt', 'search', 'creep'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print(p.communicate(b'1')[0].strip().decode('UTF-8'))
```

You can read the output of the `subprocess` by `p.stdout.readline()` command. Make sure there is something to be printed in console before writing that command. Otherwise your will program will stuck.